# Handle killing of process (c++)

Tags: c++, signals

I want my program to react on being killed by the 'killall myApplication' command.
So that it can save something and then terminate.
I know this must be done by signal handling but I am not sure which Singal it gets when being killed.

Comment: Please read the  `killall` man page, the very first line of text tells you what signal is sent.

Comment: A little help [here](http://rackerhacker.com/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/).

Comment: Also have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394250/detect-program-termination-c-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`killall` or `killall -9`? Because `-9` would mean SIGKILL, which cannot be handled nor masked (your process would be terminated right away in the scheduler, without it having any notion that any signal was sent to it).

Without `-9`, it would be SIGTERM, which can be handled. Have a look at [`man signal`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal).

Comment: I'm on an embedded system and a gpio event shall run the command 'killall myApp'. The application then has to call fflush() to write to disk. Are those calls allowed in a Signal handling function?

Comment: @tzippy From my knowledge, you can do anything in a signal handler.